# Vaadin 7 : Combobox with Icon + Caption

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I would like to create combobox component with icon+caption items. But I have no idea how to do this.
I found [an example](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6#ComboBoxStartsWith) for this but it is vaadin-6 example and codes were not fully described. Can somebody support me complete example or some useful links ? Has somebody experience on doing like this ?

I also don't want to create with deprecated codes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is vaadin7 version.](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/multiple-value/combo-box) Push the View Source (second icon) on the top right corner.

Comment: How can I figure out `ExampleUtil.getISO3166Container()` , `ExampleUtil.iso3166_PROPERTY_NAME` and  `ExampleUtil.iso3166_PROPERTY_FLAG`? I described **......and codes were not fully described** means to them. Thanks for your link sir. But I am still trouble how to start.

Comment: You can set an icon for each item with setItemIcon(), or define an item property that provides the icon resource with setItemIconPropertyId(), in a fashion similar to captions. [Here](http://vaadin.com/download/release/6.1/6.1.0/docs/example-source/com/vaadin/demo/sampler/ExampleUtil.java.html) ExampleUtil

Comment: Oh ! Thank you for `ExampleUtil.java` link. It is what I want. Now I got complete codes. Thanks.